# Which does Grogu choose?

Tags: star-wars, the-book-of-boba-fett

Luke offers Grogu a choice between "giving up attachments" and taking the Jedi path, or forsaking the Jedi way and returning to the Mandalorian- does anyone know which decision he makes?

Comment: He yeeted Luke into the sun, took the lightsaber, and ran back to Mando.

Comment: Did the next episode not make that pretty clear?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite- haven't had the chance to see it yet.

Comment: Why do people ask questions about cliffhangers without bothering to watch even the next episode?

Comment: @OrangeDog I mean, not everyone has access to a Disney+ subscription at all times. But it does feel like there are plenty of episode summaries out there on the internet that cover this already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Grogu shows up in the mail](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Grogu%27s_armor) in [Chapter 7](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_7:_In_the_Name_of_Honor) of *The Book of Boba Fett*.

[image: Grogu with mail circled]

> A shirt of beskar chainmail was created for Mandalorian foundling Grogu by the Armorer, on the commission of the Mandalorian bounty hunter Din Djarin in the years after the Galactic Civil War. After receiving the armor from Jedi Master Luke Skywalker, Grogu was presented with a choice of choosing the armor or Yoda's second lightsaber, symbolizing the path of a Jedi or giving into his attachment and returning to Djarin. Ultimately, Grogu chose the chainmail and decided to return to Din Djarin.